# Android: difference in appearance when showing ImageView and when drawing on Canvas

Tags: android, graphics

I am trying to draw an image from .png resource file.

I have tried 2 ways. When creating an ImageView and assigning it the R.drawable - the image looks fine:

[image]

But when I draw the image myself on Canvas with the following code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
options.inDither = false;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img, options);             
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y, null);
```

the image looks like this:

[image]

if you will notice, there are light grey vertical lines inside the image.

Does anyone know, why is this difference in appearance between the 2 methodologies?

Thanks,
Henry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found third way, which retains the image quality.

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img);
drawable.setBounds(x, y, x + CELL_WIDTH - 1, y + CELL_HEIGHT -1);
drawable.draw(canvas);
```